# Change the property of all objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created an object with javascript and want to make the "completed" property of all objects true.

codes:

```
let todos = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "Javascript",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "php",
    completed: false
  },
]
```

I want to make the completed property of all objects true

```
function completeAll() { 
  //some codes
 //I'm running with button
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? please add your code.

Comment: You're probably looking for [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 3):

Use `map`.

```js
let todos = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "Javascript",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "php",
      completed: false
    },
];

const output = todos.map(({completed, ...rest}) => ({...rest, completed: true}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` notation to access and change properties in the object

```js
let todos = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "Javascript",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "php",
    completed: false
  },
]
todos.forEach(function(e){
e.completed=true;
})
console.log(todos)
```